# SignalR in Xamarin forms i have configure like below but these NewJob,UpdateJob Not calling

Tags: xamarin.forms, signalr

Im Using SignalR in Xamarin forms and i have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client(V5.0.5) this plugin in all three projects.and i have added break point on all three methods like NewJob,UpdateJob but not calling .this methods working in website but not working in the Xamarin forms.

im using Xamarin.forms 5.0 version.I have spent much time on it but unable to find the reason why these methods not calling when i add job update job or delete job.

```
 private async Task ConnectExecute()
        {
          try
          {

            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("baseUrl/NeleezB2Bhubs/messages").Build();
    
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    
            hubConnection.Closed += async (s) => { await hubConnection.StartAsync(); };
    
    
            hubConnection.On<string>("JobUpdate", (item) =>
            {
              MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
              {
                try
                {
                  var newItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(item);
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
              });
            });
    
            hubConnection.On<string>("NewJob", (item) =>
            {
              MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
              {
                try
                {
                  var newItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(item);
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
              });
            });
            hubConnection.On<string>("DeleteJob", (item) =>
            {
              MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
              {
                try
                {
                  var newItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(item);
    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
              });
            });
    
    
    
    
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
    
            return;
          }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with SignalR, but it sounds like you haven't successfully connected to the hub. If you put a breakpoint on `await hubConnection.StartAsync();`, then "Step Over", does it get to the next line?  If it does, examine `hubConnection` - maybe there is some field that gives a clue what is wrong. Or a method on `hubConnection` to show errors? See section "Integrating the Hub to your Xamarin App" of [Building a Real-Time Chat App ...](https://mindofai.github.io/Building-a-Real-Time-Chat-App-With-SignalR-and-Xamarin/) - can you `SendMessage` to hub? Get back `success`?

Comment: connection succssufull there is no exception or error  the break point move to next line .

Comment: Where do you "add job" etc?  Not the code you show that is supposed to run, but code elsewhere that is supposed to send the message to your client?  Also, it might be easier to test sending a message *from* your client first - wherever your hub is running, is there a way to turn on logging, to see any incoming messages?  Then when you `SendMessage`, if you are talking to **that** hub (not just some dummy local hub or something), then log would show a message.

Comment: Also, is there sample client code you can download from some github?  Maybe a github attached with the Nuget that implements SignalR for Xamarin?  Get an existing sample app working first, is what I am thinking.